# Make Global Commandbar Back For A Frame On Page

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, frame, uwp-xaml

My first question, here it goes.

I cant seem to insert codeblocks.
(Im pretty new to UWP)

I have a WelcomePage with a CommandBar and a Frame = `MyFrame`
I have a back, forward and home button in the `CommandBar`.

```
<Frame Grid.Column="1" x:Name="MyFrame" Margin="30,50,30,30">
```

The MyFrame has a stackpanel with buttons as content to start with to navigate to other the other pages and opens them inside the `MyFrame`

I just want the back and forward button to navigate back and forward inside my frame.

Instead of the normal `Frame.GoBack()` i've tried `MyFrame.GoBack()`
It recognize `MyFrame` but it doesnt do anything....

Ive seen this example in the UWP Hamburger tutorial but i just want a commandbar 
 And not a hamburgerbar

Ive googled a lot but if I include `Frame` it just points to the basic `Frame.GoBack()`.
(Maybe i just need to learn how to google..)

Answer (score 0):

Can you actually go back???

Try navigating to one or more pages and then try going back. Here is a test code. Call the `MyFrameGoBackTest()` on the welcomepage constructor.

```
    public async void MyFrameGoBackTest()
    {

        MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(SomePage));
        await Task.Delay(5000);//5 sec
        MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(SomePage));
        await Task.Delay(5000);//5 sec
        //add a breakpoint and check the CanGoBack
        if (MyFrame.CanGoBack)
        {
            MyFrame.GoBack();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just want the back and forward button to navigate back and forward inside my frame.
>   Instead of the normal Frame.GoBack() i've tried MyFrame.GoBack() It recognize MyFrame but it doesnt do anything....

GoBack() and GoForward() works only when there is at least one entry in back/forward **navigation history**. So use your frame to navigate to other pages first, and then use GoBack() or GoForward() to move back or forward.

According to your description, I have made a **sample** for you:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
    <Frame x:Name="MyFrame" Margin="30,50,30,30" Width="500" Height="300" IsTapEnabled="True">
    </Frame>
    <CommandBar Background="Transparent" IsOpen="False">
        <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Label="Back" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Home" Label="Home" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Forward" Label="Forward" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
    </CommandBar>
</StackPanel>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page1));
    }

    private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var lable = (sender as AppBarButton).Label;
        if (lable == "Back")
        {
            if (MyFrame.CanGoBack)
            {
                MyFrame.GoBack();
            }
        }
        else if (lable == "Forward")
        {
            if (MyFrame.CanGoForward)
            {
                MyFrame.GoForward();
            }
        }
        else if (lable == "Home")
        {
            MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page1));
        }

    }
}
```

**Page1.xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Welcome Page" FontSize="50" Margin="0,20"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn2" Content="Open Page Two" Click="btn2_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**Page1.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class Page1 : Page
{
    public Page1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
    }
}
```

**Page2.xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Page Two" FontSize="50" Margin="0,20"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn2" Content="Open Page Three" Click="btn2_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**Page2.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class Page2 : Page
{
    public Page2()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page3));
    }
}
```

**Page3.xaml**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Text="Page Three" FontSize="50"/>
</Grid>
```

And the **Output** is shown as below:

[image]